# Unable to export table to excel using tableExport

Tags: javascript, html

I have all the scripts mentioned and by searching I have written the following html code:

```
 <table id="customers" class="table table-striped" >
<thead>         
    <tr class='warning'>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>%ge</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Chinna</td>
        <td>1,363,480,000</td>
        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
        <td>19.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>India</td>
        <td>1,241,900,000</td>
        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
        <td>17.4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>United States</td>
        <td>317,746,000</td>
        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
        <td>4.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Indonesia</td>
        <td>249,866,000</td>
        <td>July 1, 2013</td>
        <td>3.49</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>              
 <button onClick ="$('#customers').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});">  XLS</button>
```

The code does nothing when I click on the button. My jsfiddle link is: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12981/ What could be the reason of code not working?

Comment: It looks like the `tableExport` function uses jQuery. Do you have that included before your inclusion of the library that defines `tableExport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery ui to export to excel .

```
//table2excel.js
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
var pluginName = "table2excel",

defaults = {
    exclude: ".noExl",
            name: "Table2Excel"
};

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var e = this;

        e.template = {
            head: "<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>",
            sheet: {
                head: "<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>",
                tail: "</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>"
            },
            mid: "</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>",
            table: {
                head: "<table>",
                tail: "</table>"
            },
            foot: "</body></html>"
        };

        e.tableRows = [];

        // get contents of table except for exclude
        $(e.element).each( function(i,o) {
            var tempRows = "";
            $(o).find("tr").not(e.settings.exclude).each(function (i,o) {
                tempRows += "<tr>" + $(o).html() + "</tr>";
            });
            e.tableRows.push(tempRows);
        });

        e.tableToExcel(e.tableRows, e.settings.name);
    },

    tableToExcel: function (table, name) {
        var e = this, fullTemplate="", i, link, a;

        e.uri = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,";
        e.base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
        };
        e.format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            });
        };
        e.ctx = {
            worksheet: name || "Worksheet",
            table: table
        };

        fullTemplate= e.template.head;

        if ( $.isArray(table) ) {
            for (i in table) {
                //fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "{worksheet" + i + "}" + e.template.sheet.tail;
                fullTemplate += e.template.sheet.head + "Table" + i + "" + e.template.sheet.tail;
            }
        }

        fullTemplate += e.template.mid;

        if ( $.isArray(table) ) {
            for (i in table) {
                fullTemplate += e.template.table.head + "{table" + i + "}" + e.template.table.tail;
            }
        }

        fullTemplate += e.template.foot;

        for (i in table) {
            e.ctx["table" + i] = table[i];
        }
        delete e.ctx.table;

        if (typeof msie !== "undefined" && msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
        {
            if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
                //use blobs if we can
                fullTemplate = [fullTemplate];
                //convert to array
                var blob1 = new Blob(fullTemplate, { type: "text/html" });
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob1, getFileName(e.settings) );
            } else {
                //otherwise use the iframe and save
                //requires a blank iframe on page called txtArea1
                txtArea1.document.open("text/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, getFileName(e.settings) );
            }

        } else {
            link = e.uri + e.base64(e.format(fullTemplate, e.ctx));
            a = document.createElement("a");
            a.download = getFileName(e.settings);
            a.href = link;

            document.body.appendChild(a);

            a.click();

            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }

        return true;
    }
};

function getFileName(settings) {
    return ( settings.filename ? settings.filename : "table2excel") + ".xls";
}

$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    var e = this;
        e.each(function() {
            if ( !$.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( e, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
            }
        });

    // chain jQuery functions
    return e;
};

})( jQuery, window, document );


$("#excel").click(function(){

                    $("#customers").table2excel({
                          exclude: ".noExl",
                    name: "Excel Document customers"
                    }); 

                     });
```

Check this fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12997/